# Report created with Crystal Report in Winforms repeat pages when i use Line Graph

Tags: winforms, crystal-reports, report, sections

I have a problem when i create a report in winforms using Crystal from visual studio.

I have a table with 7 columns and i have for this case 2 rows, the colums have info like A,B,C,D,E,F,G and the rows have the values for each "sensor".

**A | B | C | D | E | F | G** 
 1 | 1 | 2  | 2  | 3  | 3 | 4 
 1 | 2 | 3  | 4  | 5  | 7 | 9

I notice that the section Details repeat for every row, i just need 1 page for all the rows. the funny thing is if i dont use any graph on the report, i just have 1 page with the details.

The graph's only shows in one page and one time, doesnt repeat and are located in the report footer.

How can i show just 1 details page and no one per each row??

Comment: So you want in 1st page values `1 | 1 | 2  | 2  | 3  | 3 | 4` and then graph, on second page values `1 | 2 | 3  | 4  | 5  | 7 | 9` and then graph, and so on or i got it wrong?

Comment: Where did you place the graph

Comment: thats something similar that is happening now, i have two details page's and i just need one, and then i have 1 page with the graph.
I need 1 page with details (cause in this page i have a matrix with all the results, thats why i dont want this page repeat), and in the other page i need just the graph. The graph now its appearing in one page.

Comment: I have some basic information in the Section2 (Page Header), then i have a matrix with the results int the Section3 (Details) and before i tried to put the graph in the Section4 (Report Footer) but this has the same problem. Now i move the graph to a GroupFooterSection to tried to solve the problem, but its the same.